# QGIS Import CSV variable conversion

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I tried to import CSV files to QGIS using the "Add delimited text layer" feature. For some reason, some of the numeric variables became QString.

How do I make them become integer so I can perform heatmap calculations?

Comment: Try this solution from @Underdark http://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/

Answer (score 3):

You can enforce the data type behaviour you want with "Add delimited text layer" using a CSVT (my previous statement was it wasn't possible at all but due to Alexandre Neto feedback, I changed my answer)

You can follow [this blog post](http://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/) to learn about CSVT files.

You can also add your CSV file with "Add Vector Layer" and use a CSVT file again.

Comment: That is not correct. You can enforce the data type in Add delimited text layer if you use a CSVT,

Comment: I tried and you were right (tested with no geometry). Thanks. I learn something too ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could run the **Refactor fields** tool from the *Processing Toolbox* to change the field type once you have added your .csv file to QGIS:

[image: Refactor fields]

You can save this as a new shapefile and use this for your heatmap analysis.